# Given a GIT URI, how can I check it out?

Tags: android, git, android-source

In [this](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/events/io/sessions/SupportingMultipleDevicesBinary.html) Google IO 2009 presentation, a GIT url is provided in the slides.
The URL looks like this

```
http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=commit;
h=a42091afb7b122c753f9050ff5dbcb792eb36a78
```

I want to check out the code, so I ran

```
git clone http://android.git.....rest...of....URI.shown..above
```

But git is aborting with the error *fatal: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server*. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: This is **gitweb** (git web interface) URL, not **repository** URL. You should have URL to use for "`git clone`" in the project summary page, as @Koraktor wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right URL should be `git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/development.git` as mentioned at the top of the web page your URL points to.

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/development.git
```